# Generate class hierarchy diagram of rails internal classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to learn the internals of Rails code and thought that it would be really helpful if i can get an overall structure of how the rails classes are organized. Does anyone know if there is a class hierarchy diagram generator rails internal classes?

Answer (score -1):

Since rails is an open source project - you can check out its classes and structure on github:
[rails github](https://github.com/rails/rails) or use the API docs: [Rails api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/)